# Magento 2: Remove coupon code from discount label

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount, order-summary

I want to remove Coupon code from Discount title on order summary from the Checkout page. please refer screenshot.

[image: nto2]

i have checked console:

```
    <tr class="totals discount">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            **<span class="title" data-bind="text: getTitle()">Discount (test5)</span>**
            <span class="discount coupon" data-bind="text: getCouponCode()">test5</span>
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': name}" data-th="checkout.sidebar.summary.totals.discount">-$8.56</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApllier">
            <plugin name="vendor_onestepcheckout_salesrule" type="Vendor\Onepagecheckout\Model\RulesApllierPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
        </type>
    </config>



    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Onepagecheckout\Model;

    class RulesApllierPlugin
    {
            public function afterAddDiscountDescription(
            \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier $rulesApplier,
            callable $proceed,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address,
            \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
        ) {
            $description = $address->getDiscountDescriptionArray();
            $ruleLabel = $rule->getStoreLabel($address->getQuote()->getStore());
            $label = '';
            if ($ruleLabel) {
                $label = $ruleLabel;
            }
            //in original method, there was a piece of code here that added the coupon code to the discount
            if (strlen($label)) {
                $description[$rule->getId()] = $label;
            }
            $address->setDiscountDescriptionArray($description);
            return $rulesApplier;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `around` plugin on the method `Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApllier::addDiscountDescription`. That's the one that adds the coupon code to the discount title.  Make it look like this:

```
public function aroundAddDiscountDescription(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier $rulesApplier,
    callable $proceed,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule
) {
    $description = $address->getDiscountDescriptionArray();
    $ruleLabel = $rule->getStoreLabel($address->getQuote()->getStore());
    $label = '';
    if ($ruleLabel) {
        $label = $ruleLabel;
    }
    //in original method, there was a piece of code here that added the coupon code to the discount

    if (strlen($label)) {
        $description[$rule->getId()] = $label;
    }
    $address->setDiscountDescriptionArray($description);
    return $rulesApplier;
}
```